# Why are generators so much slower than an iterable class?

Tags: javascript, generator

I have here two examples of RNGs that pool results from `crypto.getRandomValues` to reduce the overhead of the expensive system call. The class based approach benchmarks 378M ops/s while the generator only gets 56M ops/s. That's a 6.75x difference in performance.

```javascript
class RandClass {
    #entropy; #index
    constructor(poolSize = 1024) {
        this.#entropy = new Uint32Array(poolSize)
        this.#index = 0
        crypto.getRandomValues(this.#entropy)
    }
    next() {
        const value = this.#entropy[this.#index++]
        if (this.#index === this.#entropy.length) {
            crypto.getRandomValues(this.#entropy)
            this.#index = 0
        }
        return { value, done: false }
    }
    [Symbol.iterator]() { return this }
}

const randClass = new RandClass()

function* RandGen(poolSize = 1024) {
    const entropy = new Uint32Array(poolSize)
    while (true) {
        crypto.getRandomValues(entropy)
        for (let i = 0; i < poolSize; ++i) {
            yield entropy[i]
        }
    }
}

const randGen = RandGen()
```

Comment: i noticed that also and need an answer too

Comment: I don't know for sure, but the bottleneck might be the restoration of context. The generator version requires restoring an excution context each time the function is resumed.

Comment: How were you iterating your instances and how did you measure the throughput?

Comment: @Bergi I was calling rand*.next().value @ jsbench.me

Comment: I suspect that Noam's guess applies then. I'd expect generators to perform better when used in a `for … of` loop. Also, this would certainly be engine-dependent - what browser did you use?

Comment: @Bergi `for .. of` doesn't help , the same around 6x slower

Comment: Yes, the circumstances don't seem to matter. I fully expect co-routines to have an overhead as nothing comes for free. But I was expecting maybe 5% overhead. Maybe up to 20% overhead, or similar. Not 675%. This puts me off from even considering generators unless they are absolutely necessary or they are performing an extremely expensive task between invocations.